# How to disregard timezone using Moment.js?

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I've lost track of how many questions & responses I've read while trying to find an answer on this. The ones that *sound* like they're related often aren't, or else the users are just accused of being confused. (As an example, [the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429568/any-way-to-parse-a-time-string-using-moment-js-but-ignore-timezone-info) just tells the person asking the question that they don't really mean to be asking what they're asking. Then there's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527597/moment-js-get-date-without-considering-time-zone). The most upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385815/moment-timezones-js-how-to-convert-date-in-spesific-timezone-to-utc-disregardi) says it's just impossible. Etc., etc., etc.)

I need to be able to take a time--say 9:00 AM--and work with it as 9:00 AM *regardless of which timezone my user is in.* If a user pulls up this time in a US/Eastern timezone, they should see this value as 9:00 AM. If a user pulls up this time in a US/Pacific timezone, they should see this value as 9:00 AM. *I recognize that this is **not** actually the same moment in time, and I don't need it to be*.

To illustrate, let's call the timezone-immune timestamp I'm talking about `timezoneImmuneTimestamp`, and say that its value should always be 9:00 AM.

Say I'm executing `someMomentInUsEasternTimezone.diff(timezoneImmuneTimestamp, 'minutes')`, where `someMomentInUsEasternTimezone` is equal to 10:00AM (EST). The answer I need is 60 minutes.

Now let's add another Moment, `someMomentInUsPacificTimezone` and say its value is 11:00AM (PST). When I execute `someMomentInUsWesternTimezone.diff(timezoneImmuneTimestamp, 'minutes')`, the answer I need is 120 minutes.

Has anyone else had this particular problem, and more importantly, solved it?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't deal with this as a time at all? Just use a number of hours or minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to work with only the "wall time" of each moment object.  To do that, first create a clone of each moment and set their offsets to zero, as if they were UTC.  When doing so, pass `true` to keep the wall time instead of the same point in actual universal time.

This is described in [the docs for the `utcOffset` function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/):

> The `utcOffset` function has an optional second parameter which accepts
>   a boolean value indicating whether to keep the existing time of day.
>
> - Passing `false` (the default) will keep the same instant in Universal Time, but the local time will change.
> - Passing `true` will keep the same local time, but at the expense of choosing a different point in Universal Time.

Thus, to get the difference in minutes between `momentA` and `momentB` with respect only to wall time:

```
momentA.clone().utcOffset(0, true).diff(momentB.clone().utcOffset(0, true), 'minutes')
```

Though missing from the docs, the same argument can be passed to the `utc` function.  So if you prefer, you can shorten it to:

```
momentA.clone().utc(true).diff(momentB.clone().utc(true), 'minutes')
```

(Cloning helps the rest of your code by not mutating the original moment objects.)

Also - The Moment team highly recommends only using Moment in legacy/existing code.  If you are writing a new application, please try [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) instead. In Luxon, the [`setZone`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-setZone) function has a `keepLocalTime` option that does the same thing as I showed in Moment.

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate this *correct* response. I've spent ludicrous amounts of time on this. Just tested my application by swapping timezones, and I'm seeing exactly the behavior I was after. Thanks for all the detail and the time you spent! (And also thanks for turning me onto Luxon! I'm liking what I'm reading in the docs.)